# Disable & Enable or Drop & Create Non Clustered Indexes for Bulk Delete Operations

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance, query-performance, database-administration

I have few tables which are having millions of data. I would like to delete few of the entries on regular basis based on a column value. But most of the tables are having multiple indexes defined on it. So should i go for drop and create non clustered indexes scenario or disable and enable non clustered indexes for better performance ? I need to schedule the corresponding delete procedure as a scheduled job since this task needs to be repeated once in a week basis.

Comment: You can only know for sure by testing, but generally, if the table is huge and you are deleting a small amount of rows, the cost of recreating the indexes will far outstrip the time you gain on the delete by not having to maintain the indexes. You can also consider partitioning the table on the column to allow for deleting data by truncating partitions, which is far faster.

Answer (score 0):

For Disable index

```
 SELECT 'ALTER INDEX [' + I.name + '] ON [' + T.name + '] DISABLE' query
        FROM sys.indexes I
        INNER JOIN sys.tables T on I.object_id = T.object_id
        WHERE i.type_desc in ('NONCLUSTERED')
        and I.name is not null  
        and T.name= <table_name>
```

For Enable Index

```
 SELECT DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME(b.OBJECT_ID) table_name, SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SCHEMA_NAME, c.name, CONCAT('Alter index ', c.name, ' on ', SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id),'.',OBJECT_NAME(b.OBJECT_ID), ' Rebuild') 
              AS query, c.type_desc
            FROM sys.tables b 
            JOIN sys.indexes c ON c.object_id = b.object_id 
            where c.type_desc in('NONCLUSTERED') 
            and b.name= <table_name>
```